# How can I extend PrimeFaces datepicker js for custom year range?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, datepicker

My problem is the range of year in the datepicker while selecting is add and minus 20 years, but for my needed, I would like the range of year is currentYear-150 and currentYear+150, currentYear is 2559 and I used PrimeFaces UI framework for this project.

To solve this problem, I have written this code

```
$.extend($.datepicker._defaults, {
         options:{
             yearRange : "2409:2559"
         }
});
```

in jquery.ui.datepicker.ext.be.js (That is datepicker extension for BE because I don't need to create a new js file)

but it doesn't work, what should I do now?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I've already solved this problem by extending the Calendar class in a new file and write its constructor like this

```
public CustomCalendar() {
        //  150 Years Calendar 
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        int budhhYear=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)+543;
        int minYearRange=budhhYear-150;
        int maxYearRange=budhhYear+150;
        this.setYearRange(minYearRange+":"+maxYearRange);
}
```

Thanks for kindly helped

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<p:calendar />` component of primefaces:

```
<p:calendar yearRange="yourRange">
```

Comment: I have many p:calendar tag about thousand files, so that if I do like you said, it's difficult to maintain my project. Any solutions with custom calendar (Extends JS)?